# Problems connecting to Google Analytics APi NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, google-analytics-api

I wrote a module in NodeJS that should connect to GA. I Wrote an Authorization module an added 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics to the scope. This works an i received an token from the Google API.

With this token i tried to connect to the Google Analytics API but received an ECONNRESET error, the socket hang up.

I double checked if the application had rights to talk with the GA APi at http://code.google.com/apis/console.

This are the options i'm using to connect to the API.

```
host: 'www.googleapis.com',
port: 443,
path: '/analytics/v3/management/accounts',
method: 'GET',
headers: { Authorization: '********' }
```

Does somebody have an idea what goes wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `http` or `https`?

Comment: Solved it, i was using http instead of https